# does rbenv set the PATH variable to point to the correct ruby?

Tags: ruby, installation, rbenv

I installed rbenv and it seems and copied 2 versions of ruby to ~/.rbenv/versions, it shows
them both correctly.

When I run
    rbenv global 1.8.7-p72
It says ok and also points to it. However when I run--

```
ruby --version
```

I get ruby not found. Basically, the ruby executable is not found in the path. Can anyone help me with this problem?

My .bash_profile is
    export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
    eval "$(rbenv init -)"

rbenv versions outputs --
 1.8.7-p72
*1.9.3-p448 ( set by /home/user/.rbenv/version)

Also my ~/.rbenv/shims directory doesn't have a ruby executable. It has erb, gem,irb , rake, rdoc , ri and testrb. Could this be the issue?

I'm sorry I'm completely clueless

Answer (score 1):

- Did you execute all the step in the installation instructions https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv? I.e. did you add the required snippets to your shell startup (`.bash_profile`) and so forth?

  If you followed the instructions, could you provide the output of `rbenv versions` and `which -a ruby` for a start?

**EDIT:**

- `rbenv rehash` seems to be what generates the shims. This must be executed every time you install a new ruby version. How did you install the rubies? With `ruby-build`, as recommended in the installation instructions?

Comment: nope, I did not install using ruby-build. I did it by adding  the compiled version to ~/.rbenv/versions which according to the website is also a valid way to do it

Answer (score 0):

When I encountered this error, all I had to do was to make sure that `$PATH` had shims prior to system version of ruby like so:
`~/.rbenv/shims:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin`